# how to get ip address of client machine in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL query that inserts the content of a form into my database.

Along side inserting these values, I also want to discover and insert the users IP address.

Comment: $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];

Comment: mysql can not figure out the ip address of the client its the server side language which can see from which IP request is coming.

Comment: bt i am using trigger in mysql...and i want to know who is changing the db tables value..

Comment: to do this either you have to fetch user name and IP which can be obtained from information_schema.processlist. Now here you can always create a before insert trigger but remember triggers are not always useful and can impact DB performance if not implemented according to the requirements

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php echo $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]; ?>
```